# Get 500 error on rhel 7 django apache mod_wsgi configuration

Tags: mod-wsgi, apache2.4, rhel7, django-1.11

***I know something similar to this has been answered but I do not wish to put my django project in my /var/www/html directory as it is not considered best practices***

**My error logs read**

[Sun Aug 06 07:57:16.772735 2017] [mime_magic:error] [pid 13686] [client 37.28.197.227:53652] AH01512: mod_mime_magic: can't read `/home/ec2-user/portfolio/portfolio/wsgi.py'
[Sun Aug 06 07:57:16.772887 2017] [:error] [pid 13682] (13)Permission denied: [remote 37.28.197.227:172] mod_wsgi (pid=13682, process='d2training', application='d2training.com|'): Call to fopen() failed for '/home/ec2-user/portfolio/portfolio/wsgi.py'.

**My django.conf looks like this**

```
`<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin dondavis@d2training.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ec2-user/portfolio/
    ServerName d2training.com

    <Directory /home/ec2-user/portfolio/portfolio>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
        SetEnvIfNoCase Host d2training VALID_HOST
        Require env VALID_HOST
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ec2-user/>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ec2-user/portfolio/media>
        Require all granted
        Options Indexes
        AllowOverride all
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess d2training python-path=/home/ec2-user/py3env/:python-home=/home/ec2-user/py3env/lib/python3.4/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup d2training
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/portfolio/portfolio/wsgi.py
    Alias /media/ /home/ec2-user/portfolio/media


    ErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/django.log
    CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>`
```

** My settings.py file are as such only gave the majority of the file if you need anything else please let me know**

```
    `DEBUG = True
```

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

'# Application definition'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'd2training',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'portfolio.wsgi.application'

'# Database'
'# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
     }
}`

** And my permissions are**

So as of now I have set /home/, /home/ec2-user/, /home/ec2-user/project, /home/ec2-user/project/project/, and /home/ec2-user/project/project/wsgi.py all to 777 for access permissions but it is still giving me a 500 error.  I have even switched users to apache and was able to open the file but it is still giving me the 500 error.  pretty much everything I have found online so far has said to put it in /var/www or create a new directory in root, but neither of these options seem to be within best practices or seem secure to me.  Also I know that I should not have my entire directory open to everything but I was just trying to get this to work and then will restrict them.

Comment: Putting stuff in your home directory is worse than putting an application in a directory under ``/var/www``. You would need to open up the permissions on your home directory for it to work, and also possibly configure SELinux so that Apache can access stuff in the home directory. Why do you feel that having it in your home directory is safer from an operational stand point? If you are doing development only, use ``mod_wsgi-express`` and run stuff on an unprivileged port on the command line.

Comment: ok then where would you recommend I put my virtualenv and django directories to be served up by apache?  I am just going off of what I have read in the django tutorials and other various websites I have been reading up on.

Comment: I saw one tutorial that put them in root directory but that did not seem like a good idea to me, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The ``/root`` directory doesn't work either as ``/root`` is not readable to Apache user. So same problem as a user home directory. You could create a directory ``/var/www/sites/xxx`` where ``xxx`` is name of project. Just make sure you do not go setting ``DocumentRoot`` in ``VirtualHost`` to be a directory which is a parent to any source code, leave it unset and have it inherit the server default.

Comment: In response to putting things in the home directory I finally found the tutorial that told me I should put it in the home directory

Comment: This is from the django tutorials.

'**Where should this code live?

If your background is in plain old PHP (with no use of modern frameworks), you’re probably used to putting code under the Web server’s document root (in a place such as /var/www). With Django, you don’t do that. It’s not a good idea to put any of this Python code within your Web server’s document root, because it risks the possibility that people may be able to view your code over the Web. That’s not good for security.

Put your code in some directory outside of the document root, such as /home/mycode.**'

Comment: That information isn't really correct. It is only the directory under ``/var/www`` which holds static files. That is, the file listed as ``DocumentRoot`` in Apache configuration. Usually ``/var/www/html`` form memory, but depends on the platform. Create a new directory under ``/var/www`` such as ``/var/www/projects/mysite`` and you are fine. Putting it under a user home directory isn't usually going to work as that directory has restricted access and can't be read by others, and thus not the Apache user.